Best practices for client certificate authentication through intermediate server
I have a web application (React) that makes rest calls to a backend server (Spring boot). Depending on the request, the backend server may need to reach out to an external API that requires SSL certificates as part of the process. Is there a way to handle a situation like this where there is a server acting as a middleman between the browser and a certificate based API? Navigating to the external API in the browser directly will trigger a prompt that requests for me to identify myself via a certificate. I was hoping there would be a way to trigger this prompt in my workflow, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated

In order to authenticate against the API the backend server would need to have access to the client certificate and private key. There is no way to pass a client certificate based authentication through from the browser in a transparent way - the connection between browser and backend and between backend and API are independent TLS connections. And explicitly giving the backend server the certificates and private key is not a good idea since as the name suggests the private key should be kept private.

What if the backend server was capable of accepting the same certificates as the API? The browser could prompt for a certificate when the request to the backend server is made, then the cert could be read by the server and used to create the TLS connection to the API. Or is that also not feasible?

@urico12: Authentication with client certificates need the private key matching the certificate. Only the client (browser) has the key. The backend cannot use the certificate received from the client against the API without also having the matching private key - which the backend does not have.
